# Java Mysql connection check test

Tags: java, mysql, swing

hi all i want ask some can help me how can add mysql connection check

i want add check before start my program

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Server.SERVER_MODE = Server.MODE_LOGINSERVER;
                Config.load();
                ServerNameTable.getInstance().load();
                gsTable = new GameServerTable();

                ServerRegister frame = new ServerRegister();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: Use the JDBC driver and make a connection, may make a basic query?

Comment: *"..add mysql connection check"* .. *"`e.printStackTrace();`"* Look at the console..

Comment: i can understand you can give some explame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run a validation query before running you program. The default validation query for MySQL is:

```
SELECT 1;
```

If the query is successful it means that your client can connect to MySQL and you're ready to start your program.